# Error trying to install Certificate on browser using JS

Tags: javascript, ssl, certificate, certenroll

In my code I have a button that calls a JS file, which in turn calls a PHP file that has the API endpoints that I need to generate certificate, and sends the response back that I use in **certificate** variable below.

I'm generating the CSR myself using the openssl command.

My code to install cert on the browser is as follows (**certificate** is where I pass the certificate as response that I get from Entrust APIs)-

I'm using the code off of this page- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/01/28/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript/ (the 2nd grey block right below- *following Javascript sample shows how to install the response from the CA*)

```
function installCertificate(certificate) {
    try {
        var objEnroll = objCertEnrollClassFactory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509Enrollment");
        objEnroll.Initialize(1); // ContextUser

        objEnroll.InstallResponse(0, certificate, 6, "");

    } catch (ex) {
        swal('Error', 'Something went wrong installing Client Certificate', 'error');
        console.log("exception- " + ex.description);
    }
}
```

The error that I have is (from the catch block)-

```
CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::InstallResponse: Cannot find object or property. 0x80092004 (-2146885628 CRYPT_E_NOT_FOUND)
```

I'm not sure what it means by Cannot find object or property as it's not too verbose.

PS: If I save the response from the API as a .crt file and open it (simple double click), the certificate values look correct along with the certificate chain.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trawling I finally made it work. For anyone wondering, heres my solution-

The part of the code that generates the CSR is the 1st grey block on this page-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/01/28/how-to-create-a-certificate-request-with-certenroll-javascript.

The CSR that it comes back with has a **-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----** at the top and **-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----** at the bottom, and **line breaks** after each line.

I removed the top line and all line breaks using preg_replace like below, and as at this point the CSR does not have a line break and is just a simple string, I used a str_replace to remove the last part of it.

```
$csr = preg_replace('/^.+\n/', '', $csr);  
$csr = str_replace("-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----","", $csr);
```

**TLDR**- Removed the top and bottom line from the CSR and all the line breaks that were there. I think it had to do with how the CSR was formatted.